# Asp net core and SPA (VUE): The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html'

Tags: asp.net, azure, vue.js, asp.net-core, single-page-application

In asp net core and visual studio 2019 i have created a Vue 3 project from template:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexandredotnet.vuejsdotnetfive

In Startup.cs i have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddControllers();
     services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
     {
         configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp";
     });
 }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }

     app.UseRouting();
     app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
     app.UseAuthorization();

     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         endpoints.MapControllers();
     });

     app.UseSpa(spa =>
     {
         if (env.IsDevelopment())
             spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp/";
         else
             spa.Options.SourcePath = "dist";

         if (env.IsDevelopment())
         {
             spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve");
         }

     });
    }
```

When i deploy to azure i get an internal error. So i've tried to launch in production mode on my laptop
setting:

```
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
```

in launchSetting.json. It's created the "dist" folder as in the image below:

[image]

Why i have the folowing error??:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.


at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__1(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.TryServeStaticFile(HttpContext context, String contentType, PathString subPath)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.<Use>b__2()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__0(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
Il thread 0x30e8 è terminato con il codice 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Your `app.UseSpaStaticFiles()` call looks very different from what I see on extension page...

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue. Here is my resolution:

```
var spaStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
{
  FileProvider = new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(System.IO.Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp/dist"))
};

app.UseSpaStaticFiles(spaStaticFileOptions);
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    if (IsDevelopment(env))
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp/";
    else
    {
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = spaStaticFileOptions;
        //spa.Options.SourcePath = "dist";
    }

    if (IsDevelopment(env))
    {
        spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve");
    }
});

bool IsDevelopment(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    return !IsProduction(env);
}
bool IsProduction(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    return prodEnvironments.Contains(env.EnvironmentName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was running my development website in a local IIS environment because IIS Express was unreliable and regularly went into a timeout. For the local IIS development application pool I used a custom local user account with what appeared to be insufficient access rights. I placed this account in the 'local admin group' and then after issuing the IISRESET cmd the error went away.

I know it is generally (very) bad practice to put application pool accounts in the local admin group but I only had to do this for the Development environment. I will update this answer when I get it to work with only 'Users' level access rights.